# SQL Running Sum with flags at certain amounts

Tags: sql, sum

I am trying to create a query to sum total gifts given by a certain person, but to add a flag on the individual gift when the total giving hits $500 (I don't need to sum past that).

I have the Persons ID, the gift size, and the gift date. for example:

```
ID           gift_date       gift_amt
---------    -----------     --------------  
1            1/6/09          500
2            1/9/09          200
2            1/15/09         65
3            1/26/09         140
2            2/10/09         600
3            3/7/09          200
```

I would like a flag to be shown in my query for ID# 1 on the row with gift_date of 1/6/09, for ID#2 for gift date 2/10/09 and no flag for ID#3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL 8.4`:

```
SELECT  q.*, CASE WHEN psum > 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
FROM    (
        SELECT  gd.*, SUM(gift_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY gift_date) AS psum
        FROM    gift_date gd
        ) q
WHERE   psum <= 500 - gift_amt
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically this would be done by the View (as in [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)).  Most often this would be a grid control that has grouping functionality, rather than when the data is loaded.  You would then load the data from the database as you showed above, and configured the view to display the grouped data.

Comment: My plan is to put this into a view once I join it with the information I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean view as in a database view, I meant view as in model-view-controller.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you at all:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3112381/SQL-Server-Calculating-Running-Totals-Subtotals-and-Grand-Total-Without-a-Cursor.htm

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server version 2005+, use below query if you will need only flag column

```
--suppose this is your table
DECLARE @Table TABLE 
(
    ID int,gift_date datetime,gift_amt int
)
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT 1,'1/6/09',500 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'1/9/09',200 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'1/15/09',65 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'1/26/09',140 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2/10/09',600 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'3/7/09',200

;WITH CTE As 
(
    SELECT ID,gift_date,gift_amt,
    SUM(gift_amt)OVER(PARTITION BY ID) As TotalSum
    FROM @Table
)
SELECT ID,gift_date,gift_amt,
CASE WHEN TotalSum>500 then 1 else 0 end as Flag
FROM CTE
```